# How to insert a Set into a column of type integer[]?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I have a column of type `integer[]`, created with the following query.

```
...
questions int[] DEFAULT '{}',
...
```

I am trying to insert a set of integers using Hibernate's query functionality.

```
Set<Integer> questions = randomQuestions();
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE contestant SET questions=:questions WHERE email=:email");
query.setParameterList("questions", questions);
query.setParameter("email", email);
query.executeUpdate();
```

This doesn not successfully execute and throws and exception.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "questions" is of type integer[] but expression is of type record
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

How will I go about inserting my set of integers into the database?

Answer (score 1):

```
query.setParameterList("questions", questions.toArray(new Integer[]));
```

try above , this should work.(Haven't tried though)